Why does MAUI Archive Distribution for IOS fail with "A connection to a Mac is required in order to continue" even when paired to a MAC?
my MAUI app archive distribution fails since last week with the output "A connection to a Mac is required in order to continue", although visual studio is paired to a MAC.
Meaning, i can:

build the app paired to the mac
archive the app paired to the mac
but upon archive distribution the distribution immediately fails with "A connection to a Mac is required in order to continue".

Anybody expirienced this in the past?
I am really stumped because it worked in the past until renew of the distribution certificate and it still works for other apps. Also the error is misleading, since the mac connection is active...
Xamarin Output
I tried:

to sync and renew all profiles
restart the mac
restart VS and the PC
deleted bin and obj folders
deleted the xma server on the MAC

etc... No chance, archive distribution always fails with this one app.
Funny enough, other apps still can be distributed normally, just with this one it stopped working.
Only thing i did was renew the app distribution certificate.

Ok, i just found a workaround by distributing the Archive from Xcode. But i still don’t know why i cant distribute the Archive from the connected pc anymore…
